# how do I search for file names that contain a blank so I can eliminate the blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, wildcard

For the following,  N represents a Numeral and S&F represents Letters in Surname and Firstname:

I have created a file structure of some 6,500 pdf images with  file names generally of the format NNN.SSSSS.FFFFF.pdf which I need to standardise upon,
however some filenames I have created have a blank inserted after the first dot like in this example NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf. The blank preceding some Surnames affects Surname sort orders

I want to search My Google Drive for filenames that contain a blank after the dot after the numerals.  Having done that search, I may manually remove the blanks by renaming or I may create a google script if there are too many.
Ultimately I think I need a wildcard for a numeral. And assuming %20 represents a blank I have tried the following in search fields but I am not finding the NNN. SSSSS files.

%20
.%20
".%20"
<>*.%20 here <>* I thought meant not a letter????

help please
regards Des

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the filename from `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` to `NNN.SSSSS.FFFFF.pdf` of the PDF file.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Flow:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the regex cannot be used for [the search query](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref). By this, the files with the filename of the pattern like `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` cannot be directly retrieved. So I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve PDF files in the folder.
2. Check the filename using regex.

   - In this case, I use `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.pdf` as the regex.
3. Change the filename from `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` to `NNN.SSSSS.FFFFF.pdf`.

#### Sample

```
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  // 1. Retrieve PDF files in the folder.
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const filename = file.getName();
    
    // 2. Check the filename using regex.
    if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.pdf/.test(filename)) {

      // 3. Change the filename
      file.setName(filename.replace(/ /g, ""));
    }
  }
}
```

- If you want to retrieve all PDF files in the Drive, please use the following script.

  ```
    const files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      const filename = file.getName();
      if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.pdf/.test(filename)) {
        file.setName(filename.replace(/ /g, ""));
      }
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- In this regex, the alphabet and number are checked. If the specific characters are included in the pattern of `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf`, please tell me.

#### References:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getname)
- [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename)

### Added

- From `By NNN I should have said these are numerals ranging from 001 to 999.`, I understood `NNN` is 3 digit number.
- From `In the same sense that SSSSS represents a Surname having multitude of letters and ranging in length.`, I understood that `SSSSS` is the strings of 5 characters.

From above, the modified sample script is as follows.

#### Sample

```
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const filename = file.getName();
    if (/[0-9]{3}\. [a-zA-Z]{5}\. [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.pdf/.test(filename)) {
      file.setName(filename.replace(/ /g, ""));
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
function myFunction() {
  const files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '. ' and mimeType='application/pdf'");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const filename = file.getName();
    if (filename.includes(". ")) {
      file.setName(filename.replace(/ /g, ""));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not `name contains '. '` or `fn.match(/\. /)` ?

Comment: @pguardiario Thank you for your comment. I had thought that OP need to use the pattern of `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` from question. If my understanding is not correct, please tell me. If OP's goal is to remove `. ` to `.` in all patterns, I think that the script becomes simple. About `name contains '. '`, if you want to use it, I think that you can use `const files = DriveApp.searchFiles("name contains '. ' and mimeType='application/pdf'")`. This might be able to reduce the cost.

Comment: Thankyou both. By NNN I should have said these are numerals ranging from 001 to 999. In the same sense that SSSSS represents a Surname having multitude of letters and ranging in length. The important factor is the character before the dot is a numeral.Then immediately following the dot is a blank or space. Trying to search for ‘. ‘ does not work. Neither does “. “ Searching on MyDrive using both ‘. ‘ and “. “ pull up file names with and without blanks. Regards Des

Comment: @Kiwi Des Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @pguardiario By the way, when `DriveApp.searchFiles` is used, I forgot that it was required to use the search query of Drive API v2. In this case, `const files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '. ' and mimeType='application/pdf'")`

Comment: @Kiwi Des By the way, I understood your goal like "You want to change the filename from `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` to `NNN.SSSSS.FFFFF.pdf` of the PDF file.". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Tanaike, your English is very good.  Much better than my use of programming language.  Yes my ultimate aim is to remove those two blanks as you show.  And the most important to get rid of is the first blank as I sort on Surname and the first blank spoils the sort order.  
Note also, the  parts of my file name come from another database, not mine, so I can not change them without losing relativity. Thank you, regards Des

Comment: @Kiwi Des Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current issue using my proposed script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Unfortunately, in my environment, I can confirm that all proposed scripts converts the filename from `NNN. SSSSS. FFFFF.pdf` to `NNN.SSSSS.FFFFF.pdf`. I would like to think of your current issue by correctly understanding it. I deeply apologize for this.